# Aliased signal has phase shift due to Nyquist

Tags: nyquist-plot

Let's say I have a pure sinusoid at 135MHz and I am sampling at 150MHz (so fin < 2fs). So now in my first Nyquist zone, I will see a 15MHz alised component.

From my understanding, the 15MHz signal and the 135MHz signal will look the exact same when sampled. I read somewhere that, they will have a phase shift though.

Where does the phase shift come from, and is it not possible to use that phase shift to distinguish between the two?

Comment: To use the phase shift you would have to measure the phase relative to some other signal. What would you intend to use as the reference and how would you sample it. (I don't have a clue.)

Comment: My suggestion is to look at the signals in the time domain on an excel spreadsheet. Draw in the sample points also as vertical lines. Maybe this will bring some kind of insight. I don't know the answer to your question. Otherwise I would answer it.

Comment: You may can use correlation to measure the phase shift.  See [this document](http://www.eecs.umich.edu/courses/eecs206/archive/spring02/lab.dir/Lab3/lab3_v3_0_release.pdf) for example.

Comment: I suppose it would be good to clarify what phase shift is being considered. Do we have two signals, sampled separately? Or do we have two signals added together as if by a summing op-amp?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I'm wondering where the phase shift is coming from? Why is there one in the first place.

Comment: Phase shift between what and what? The equation for a 15 MHz signal is A*sin(15MHz*2*pi*t). The equation for 135 MHz is A*sin(135MHz*2*pi*t). If you sample either signal starting at t=0 at a frequency of 150 MHz, you will get identical results. So, no phase shift. If you say there is a phase shift somewhere it is your job to explain it.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with mkeith's answer, but would add that if you have the liberty of changing the sampling rate, you can distinguish an aliased from a non-aliased signal.

For example, if you sample at 140 MHz instead of 150 MHz, a 15 MHz signal still shows up at 15 MHz. A 135 MHz signal shows up at 5 MHz instead of at 15 MHz. I have actually used this observation before to figure out if the signal I was looking at was aliased or not.

Comment: Also, if you don't WANT the 15 MHz signal, you can high pass filter prior to sampling to eliminate it. Basically if the bandwidth of the sampled signal is known, and is less than Fs/2, then any aliasing can be resolved unambiguously.

Answer (score 2):

After poking around with excel, I am quite sure that there is no difference. If both signals start with phase = 0 at time T = 0, then their time series is identical to each other. So the Fourier transform will be identical and there will be no phase difference between the signals as sampled.

[image]

In this picture I graphed a 135 MHz waveform, a 15 MHz waveform and also put vertical lines at all the places where the waveforms would be sampled with a 150 MHz clock. As you can see, all the sample points are places where the waveforms intersect. So the samples generated from a 15 MHz waveform and a 135 MHz waveform are identical when sampled at 150 MHz. It is not clear what phase shift or phase difference you are talking about.

If you sum together 135 MHz + 15 MHz in the time domain, then sample the sum, the exact result depends on the phase shift between them, but the result will always be equivalent to a 15 MHz waveform whose amplitude is between 0 and the sum of the two amplitudes.

So there is no getting around the aliasing effect.